# Own code in Wordpress header

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

Let us say I wanted to access the header of my Wordpress blog and stick some code in it, like an embedded youtube video and Facebook brand page. How and where would I do this?

In other words, instead of the usual image I would like my own content and then for the blog to start below it.

Any help or questions welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the `header.php` file directly. This is a pretty messy solution though. It may be better to [register a sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) in the header and then use a widget to place a block of text/html in there. This way will allow you to manage the content of that area directly from the administration backend rather than having to vi into the header file each time you want to make changes.